# analyze show copywithzone is leaking, is it false alarm?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my app I want to copy a custom class from one array to another array. So I implemented copyWithZone for this class. Xcode analyze warning me that every line with [alloc] or [copy] are leaking memory. How can I tell if it's really leaking or it's the copied instance that I need?

```
@implementation MyClass

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {

    MyClass *copy = [[MyClass allocWithZone:zone] init];
    if (copy){
        copy.uniqueId = [uniqueId copy];
    }

    return copy; 
}
```

Comment: Are you getting the analyzer warning in this code, or is the warning showing up in another class file?  If it is in another class, please include that code.

Comment: I tried to profile my app. Once the copied object get removed from the target array, profiler would report leak in this copyWithZone code. allocWithZone and copy both lines leak memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your `uniqueId` property declared as a retain property? If so, this line is leaking:

```
copy.uniqueId = [uniqueId copy];
```

Change it to:

```
copy.uniqueId = [[uniqueId copy] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite right.

The line

```
copy.uniqueId = [uniqueId copy];
```

should probably be

```
copy.uniqueId = self.uniqueId;
```

That way you'll get correct semantics for the property no matter if it is declared as copy, retain or assign.

Also, I wouldn't bother with the test for `copy != nil`.  Sending `setUniqueId:` to nil is a no op.

**Edit**

By the way

```
copy.uniqueId = [uniqueId copy];
```

leaks if the property is retain or copy since `[uniqueId copy]` gives you an object you own and you don't release or autorelease it before the end of the scope.

Comment: If the OP wants a deep copy, though, that won't work like they want.

Comment: @kubi: itr will if the property is declared as copy.  If the property is not declared as copy then you could argue they don't want a deep copy.